# Django - DRF Validations

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-validation

I'm designing an API which will be consumed by different partners. Following is the API dummy payload:-

```
{
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2,
    key3: value3,
    key4: value4,
    key5: value5,
    partner: partner_code
}
```

Now, I've got a model in which above fields need to be saved.

```
class Table(models.Model):
    key1 = models.IntegerField()    
    key2 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)    
    key3 = models.IntegerField()
    key4 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)    
    key5 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    partner = models.ForeignKey(Partner)
```

Also, I've a serializer:-

```
class TableSerializer(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        model = Table
        fields = '__all__'
```

Now, whenever the data is POSTed, I serialize(and **validate**) the data, and then save it. Here's how I do it.

```
serializer = TableSerializer(data=payload)
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
```

This is the normal DRF flow. Now, the problem that is arising is that I need to apply custom validations wrt to each partners. For eg:-

```
`key2` and `key4` are mandatory for PartnerA. Similarly, for PartnerB, max value of `key1` is 100 and many more.
```

As per the current DRF flow, I need to add `if-else` conditions in serializers.

```
class TableSerializer(models.Model):
    def validate(self, data):
        if partner == `partnerA`:
            # checkfor key1 max value.
            # check the mandatory fields.
        elif partner == `partnerB`:
            # some custom validations
        # and so on
    class Meta:
        model = Table
        fields = '__all__'
```

This `if-else` can keep on growing which is a bad design. How can I introduce another component named as **`Validation Engine`** that can first validate the data and then pass on the validated data to DRF serializers?

Answer (score 0):

You can write some more serializers(this serializers will be only for validation) with partner == `partnerB` or something like so and do this staff:

```
def validate(self, data):
    data_is_valid = False
    for serializer_class in selializers_for_validate:
        serializer = serializer_class(data=data)
        is_valid = serializer.is_valid()
        if is_valid:
            break
    if not is_valid:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(<here your custom error>)
    return data
```

I think this decision is not so good, but you can try,
or you can write your custom validators and use it in validate

Answer (score 0):

I propose to make base serializer with only basic validation and a map between partners id/name/type/etc to the specific serializer:

```
from django.db import models
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet


# models.py
class Table(models.Model):
    key1 = models.IntegerField()
    key2 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    key3 = models.IntegerField()
    key4 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    key5 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    partner = models.ForeignKey(Partner)


# serializers.py
class TableSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    partner_serializers = {}

    class Meta:
        model = Table
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate(self, data):
        self.partner_serializers[data['partner']['partner_id']](
            instance=self.instance,
            data=data
        ).is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        return super().validate(data)

    @classmethod
    def register_partner_validator(cls, partner_id):
        def wrapped(serializer):
            cls.partner_serializers[partner_id] = serializer
            return serializer

        return wrapped


@TableSerializer.register_partner_validator('thePartner1')
class Partner1TableSerializer(TableSerializer):
    class Meta:
        extra_kwargs = {
            'key3': {'max_value': 3}
        }

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['key1'] + data['key2'] > 5:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Wrong!')


@TableSerializer.register_partner_validator('thePartner2')
class Partner2TableSerializer(TableSerializer):
    def validate(self, data):
        if data['key1'] + data['key5'] < 5:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Wrong!')


# views.py
class TableViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Table.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TableSerializer
```